# Django: avoid data type limitation

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I have a class which has an `IntegerField` attr.
In its `ModelForm`, in the field of this attr, I need to send a String, which later will store an Integer once it is processed in the view.
The problem is that Django doesn't allows this, and when I use `form.cleaned_data.get('myattr')` it's saying that it's wrong because it should be an Integer.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    teacher = models.IntegerField(null=False) # I'm saving teacher's key here


class Teacher(models.Model:
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 50, null=False)
    key = models.IntegerField(null=False)


class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    teacher = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Teacher.objects.all(), label='Select the teacher')
```

So, when the user is selecting the student's teacher, that select field will display the name of the teachers available. But in the model it will store their key, which I manage in view.

views.py:

```
teacher = form.cleaned_data.get('teacher') # it has the name
teacher = Teacher.objects.get(name=teacher).key # getting the key in order to store an Integer, but Django is banning my code before anyway.
```

How can I handle this without changing the data type of the model?

I even added `to_field_name` in the form field with the value of the Teachers' key.

Comment: a `ModelChoiceField` is for selecting an object that is referenced by a `ForeignKey` in the model. So it needs the `pk` (primary key) of the `Teacher` instance as input. Why don't you use `ForeignKey` for the `teacher` field? You're making your code too complicated the way you're doing it now.

Comment: Because I'm migrating a desktop app to a web app and I have to keep the structure of the tables. Job stuff

Comment: Then make sure your HTML form is posting the `pk` as value (a <select> field's <option>s have visible values, for which you can use the name, and the actual posted values, for which you should use the `pk`). If you're using `{{ form.teacher }}` in your template this should just work.

Comment: Well, if I inspect the element, in the <option> tag it's showing the pk in the value attr, and displaying the name. Since I've used to_field_name with the pk. I can't get why is the view receiving a string from the post method.

Comment: what exactly is the error you're getting? show us your template, the error traceback, and the contents of `request.POST`. Note that everything is always posted as string, even integers. They are cast back to whatever is needed when the form field fetches the value (and cleans it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One better approach here will be to setup a relationship between your student and teacher(using foregin key).

Depending of the need of your app here is how to do:

If one student can have several teachers and one teacher can have several students : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

If one student can have only one teacher but a teacher can have multiple students:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

If one student can only have one teacher, and one teacher can only have one student:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

This is the best way to manage this.
Then you only have to map the Student model in the Student form like:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        #you can add the list of all the fields you want there
        fields = ['teacher']
```

One extra step will be to define the **str** method of the model so Django will associate a string representation of your model in your form (Here for having a nice way to display Teacher in the student form).

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 50, null=False)
    #place other fields here ...

    def __str__(self):
        #if you print a Teacher django will return the string corresponding to the teacher name
        return self.name
```

Comment: I absolutely appreciate your answer. It's useful, but not in this case since I'm migrating a desktop app to a web app, and the company wants to keep the structure of their tables. That's why I'm trying to manage this in some other way.
If I could just make the code ignore the data type...

Comment: And what if you add the meta description of Student in the student form.
Then use a Select as a form widget and inside the __init__ populate the select from the database query?